# Pass session variable from one ear to another ear

Tags: jsp, jboss, struts2

Actually i have deployed two ears test.ear and test1.ear on jboss 5.x server. 
test.ear contains index.jsp page in this jsp i have set a session variable like :

```
session.setAttribute("Initiated","true")
```

From index.jsp i am forwarding control to action(struts2 action class) class present in test1.ear.
But when i am retrieving variable from action class,it is null

```
Map session = (Map)ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
String sessionExistence=(String)session.get("Initialted");
```

So How can i share session variable from jsp of test.ear to struts2 action class present in test1.ear.

Comment: The question title made me laugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have sharing session across different applications. The reason is simple, there will be conflicts in attribute names which might result in overriding values.

You can only send parameters along with the request while forwarding to another application.

Comment: It is possible, however, in WebLogic as an optional configuration.

Comment: @rees is it possible in jboss7?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I don't think that JBoss 7 offers this support currently.  It appears that they once planned to add it to earlier versions, but it kept getting backlogged in favor of higher priorities and never got implemented.  And although I haven't ever used WebSphere myself, WebSphere appears to offer this feature as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share in-memory (or persistent too) information between several different applications consider using a Data Grid like [Infinispan](http://www.infinispan.org)
See an [Infinispan tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/248-infinispan-tutorial-part-1.html) to get started. hope it helps.